# Is this a ddd anti-pattern?

Tags: repository, domain-driven-design, entities

Is it a violation of the Persistance igorance to inject a repository interface into a Entity object Like this. By not using a interface I clearly see a problem but when using a interface is there really a problem? Is the code below a good or bad pattern and why?

```
public class Contact
{
    private readonly IAddressRepository _addressRepository;

    public Contact(IAddressRepository addressRepository)
    {
        _addressRepository = addressRepository;
    }

    private IEnumerable<Address> _addressBook;
    public IEnumerable<Address> AddressBook
    {
        get
        {
            if(_addressBook == null)
            {
               _addressBook = _addressRepository.GetAddresses(this.Id);
            }
            return _addressBook;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly a good idea, but it may be ok for some limited scenarios. I'm a little confused by your model, as I have a hard time believing that Address is your aggregate root, and therefore it wouldn't be ordinary to have a full-blown address repository. Based on your example, you probably are actually using a table data gateway or dao rather than a respository.

I prefer to use a data mapper to solve this problem (an ORM or similar solution). Basically, I would take advantage of my ORM to treat address-book as a lazy loaded property of the aggregate root, "Contact". This has the advantage that your changes can be saved as long as the entity is bound to a session.

If I weren't using an ORM, I'd still prefer that the concrete Contact repository implementation set the property of the AddressBook backing store (list, or whatever). I might have the repository set that enumeration to a proxy object that does know about the other data store, and loads it on demand.

Comment: The code is a pure example and is not based on any real code, but I agree the AddressRepository was a bad example

Comment: @JasonTrue, What is wrong with an Address being an aggregate root?  If multiple contacts would share the same address (e.g. contacts from the  same company who don't have ownership of the addresses), how would you model it?  They couldn't be VOs if they have a unique identity.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the load function from outside. The new `Lazy<T>` type in .NET 4.0 comes in handy for that:

```
    public Contact(Lazy<IEnumerable<Address>> addressBook)
    {
        _addressBook = addressBook;
    }

    private Lazy<IEnumerable<Address>> _addressBook;
    public IEnumerable<Address> AddressBook
    {
        get { return this._addressBook.Value; }
    }
```

Also note that `IEnumerable<T>`s might be intrinsically lazy anyhow when you get them from a query provider. But for any other type you can use the `Lazy<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you follow DDD you always operate with *the whole* aggregate. The repository always returns you a fully loaded aggregate root.

It doesn't make much sense (in DDD at least) to write code as in your example. A Contact aggregate will always contain all the addresses (if it needs them for its behavior, which I doubt to be honest).

So typically ContactRepository supposes to construct you the whole Contact aggregate where Address is an entity or, most likely, a value object inside this aggregate.

Because Address is an entity/value object that belongs to (and therefore managed by) Contact aggregate it will not have its own repository as you are not suppose to manage entities that belong to an aggregate outside this aggregate.

Resume: always load the whole Contact and call its behavior method to do something with its state.

Answer (score 0):

Since its been 2 years since I asked the question and the question somewhat misunderstood  I will try to answer it myself.

Rephrased question:
"Should Business entity classes be fully persistance ignorant?"

I think entity classes should be fully persistance ignorant, because you will instanciate them many places in your code base so it will quickly become messy to always have to inject the Repository class into the entity constructor, neither does it look very clean. This becomes even more evident if you are in need of injecting several repositories. Therefore I always use a separate handler/service class to do the persistance jobs for the entities. These classes are instanciated far less frequently and you usually have more control over where and when this happens. Entity classes are kept as lightweight as possible.

I now always have 1 Repository pr aggregate root and if I have need for some extra business logic when entities are fetched from repositories I usually create 1 ServiceClass for the aggregate root.

By taking a tweaked example of the code in the question as it was a bad example I would do it like this now:

Instead of:

```
public class Contact
{
    private readonly IContactRepository _contactRepository;

    public Contact(IContactRepository contactRepository)
    {
        _contactRepository = contactRepository;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _contactRepository.Save(this);
    }
}
```

I do it like this:

```
public class Contact
{

}

public class ContactService
{
    private readonly IContactRepository _contactRepository;

    public ContactService(IContactRepository contactRepository)
    {
        _contactRepository = contactRepository;
    }

    public void Save(Contact contact)
    {
        _contactRepository.Save(contact);
    }
}
```